# How can I fix Windows boot problems from Linux?

Tags: windows-7, grub, grub2, ubcd

Is there some way I can fix Windows boot-problems from Linux (Like I could use EasyBCD from Windows)

When it is booting, it is booting to a corrupt Windows 7 version, though I do have a working Windows 8 partition that should be OK.  I could install a new Windows, but I don't know exactly where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) to delete the corrupt Windows partition and extend the working Windows partition to use up all the new available space.

Comment: I can install gparted into my present Linux

Comment: @Olav ok then, launch it from there :)